# How to insure no missed inbound Twilio SMS messages via RestAPI?

Tags: twilio

I’m looking for “best practices” advice regarding guaranteeing that no inbound messages get lost.   I’m specifically concerned about downtime on our HTTP listener, whether due to scheduled or unscheduled events, as well as the possibility  that routing issues outside of our control might prevent Twilio from even reaching our server.

The App Monitor screen on the Twilio site has a detail of all the incoming messages that failed to be delivered to the Request URL, but unless I missed it, I don’t see any access to it via the API.

I thought about sending a dummy message specifying the callback url, as a means of confirming that Twilio can access our site, but even at one message every minute, it could still miss brief outages due to transient routing issues.  The Fallback URL doesn’t really address my concerns either, since it could be affected by the same issues that affect the primary request URL.

The only way I can see to do this is to periodically use the Message List Resource to compare against a database of received messages on the HTTP listener, but I don’t like the fact that it’s limited to filtering granularity of 24 hours.  Ideally, I’d want to run this “cross check” procedure every 5 to 10 minutes or so, and specify a range of timestamps to minimize the amount of unnecessary CPU / database access.

Has anyone come up with any clever solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

One option to catch this could be using [App Monitor Triggers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/app-monitor-triggers?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon). You can [create a new Alert Trigger](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/triggers/alert/create?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon) for any error with a "Trigger Value" of 1. The Trigger Value is the amount of times this occurrence has to happen before you get a notification (either via e-mail or a webhook). This setup means the first time an error happens you'll get notified. Allowing you to catch transient issues like you outlined above.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, but doesn't really get at the heart of the problem.  True, it would enable me to know I missed a message, but (unless I'm missing something), it doesn't help to identify the specific messages I missed.  In other words, yes, I could use this to know I had a problem, but would still need to use the Message List Resource (with it's limited filtering capabilities) to get at those missed messages.